# SQL query to get rows that does not comply with given rule

Tags: sql

I have a list of products in my database.

| PRODUCTID | UNITS |
| --- | --- |
| PROD1 | 1 |
| PROD2 | 2 |
| PROD3 | 3 |
| PROD4 | 1 |
| PROD5 | 1 |

Each of them are sold in one or multiple **units of measure**.

| UNITOFMEASUREID |
| --- |
| Kg |
| Pc |
| Pk |
| Ctn |
| Bx |

| PRODUCTID | UNITOFMEASUREID | ISBASEUNIT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **PROD1** | **Kg** | **False** |
| PROD2 | Kg | True |
| PROD2 | Pk | False |
| PROD3 | Kg | True |
| PROD3 | Pc | False |
| PROD3 | Ctn | False |
| **PROD4** | **Ctn** | **False** |
| PROD5 | Bx | True |

All of the products need one of the units to be marked as the **base unit of measure**.
Unfortunately the quality of the data is not 100%. And I need to find all products that does not have any base units of measure set.

In the above scenario I would like to write an SQL-query that give the me the two lines marked in bold.

| PRODUCTID | UNITOFMEASUREID | ISBASEUNIT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PROD1 | Kg | False |
| PROD4 | Ctn | False |

I have tried to write some SQL including "GROUP BY" but my knowledge is not good enough to solve this one on my own. Hopefully someone else might help me out.

Comment: If **you** "have to write it" there's not much we can do....  (stackoverflow is not a free code writing service)

Comment: Thank you for your constructive feedback @Luuk. Im stuck on a problem, I ask for help. I will post my non working queries if that makes you happy.

Comment: Yes, the non-working queries is a good thing. Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.  Plus, it gives us a place to start from, rather from zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use MAX and GROUP by. Because T is after F in the alphabet if one of the values is True then MAX for that productID is True. We then use HAVING to get the values where the MAX is not True.
There products are therefore the products which do not have a unit of measure marked True, whether the value is False, empty or null.

```
SELECT 
  productid,
  MAX(isbaseunit)
FROM 
  UNITOFMEASUREID
GROUP BY
  productid
HAVING
  MAX(isbaseunit) <> 'True';
```

Comment: You answer is dependant of database type. Some databases recognize boolean and other not. So sometimes TRUE or FALSE are a strings and sometimes they ara boolean !

Comment: Looks like this came close to what I needed. Did not know of the HAVING, thanks!
I posted my final working query below.

Answer (score 0):

This is my final, working query. Thanks @Kendle.

```
SELECT
  productid,
  MAX(CONVERT(varchar, isbaseunit)) as Units
FROM
  UNITOFMEASUREID
GROUP BY
  productid
HAVING
  MAX(CONVERT(varchar, isbaseunit)) <> 'True'
AND
  MAX(CONVERT(varchar, isbaseunit)) = 0
```